# Jquery how to set params when option is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML:

```
<select style="color:#666666;font-size:11px;" name="sort" id="sort"><option value="1">senest tilføjet</option>
<option value="rating">highest rating</option>
<option value="ratings">most votes</option>
<option value="created_at">after latest date</option>
</select>
```

I want to sort the params depending on the selected option.

Example: If the user choose to sort after highest rating, the page would update and have the params: `?sort=rating` in the url.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what data source will be sorted? Also, why don't you use postbacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will make the page refresh with a new query string when an option is selected.

```
$("#sort").change(function() {
  window.location.search = "?sort=" + $(this).val();
});
```

You can [see it in action on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/iforat/2).

Comment: The problem is that the param is added when clicked. It should be when selected and also there is a problem when there already is a sort param. It will just add multiple, when there should only be 1 sort param.

Comment: @Railsbeginner I noticed that and so I edited my answer. Refresh the page and look at my edit.